# Use Single Select Statement to Search within all Table within a database

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union-all

Hi guys any simple way of using this SELECT STATEMENT in MYSQL.
The idea is to try and use 1 Statement to Search within all Tables from *DataBase1*

```
SELECT NAME,ADDRESS,DATA FROM DataBase1.Table1 WHERE ADDRESS IN('India','Japan') UNION ALL

SELECT NAME,ADDRESS,DATA FROM DataBase1.Table2 WHERE ADDRESS IN('India','Japan') UNION ALL

SELECT NAME,ADDRESS,DATA FROM DataBase1.Table3 WHERE ADDRESS IN('India','Japan')
```

Thank u in advance

Comment: Your query is fine . . . well, except that the last two subqueries are the same.

Comment: Enumerated table names usually indicate bad database planning/design

Comment: i have rectified.plz give resolution.

Comment: As stated above, this looks like some bad design.  Wouldn't it be better to have a single address table which are referred to by these other tables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to get the current ordinal number of a fetched row in MySQL; reading around in StackOverflow, you would need a variable to achieve that.

The query below will generate this report - format it as plain text and save it to file to get an SQL script:

```
UNION ALL SELECT NAME,ADDRESS,DATA FROM DataBase1.Table1 WHERE ADDRESS IN('India','Japan') 
UNION ALL SELECT NAME,ADDRESS,DATA FROM DataBase1.Table2 WHERE ADDRESS IN('India','Japan') 
UNION ALL SELECT NAME,ADDRESS,DATA FROM DataBase1.Table3 WHERE ADDRESS IN('India','Japan')
```

You would then have to remove the first `UNION ALL` from the generated query, or replace it with ten spaces to remain aligned.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT (
    'UNION ALL '
  , 'SELECT NAME,ADDRESS,DATA FROM '
  , table_schema
  , '.'
  , table_name 
  , ' WHERE ADDRESS IN(''India'',''Japan'')'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = 'Database1'
```

If there is a way to get the current row number, you could replace the first argument of the `CONCAT()` function with the expression:
`CASE row_number WHEN 1 THEN '           ' ELSE 'UNION ALL ' END`, to get a complete SQL statement, ready to run, in your report.